# Distribution of a constrained Gaussian distribution in frequency domain

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, fourier-transform, truncation

We know that a Gaussian Distribution is not limited and it spans from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ . However, practically if we sample the Gaussian with a finite sampling frequency, the maximum frequency is a finite value and it may happen sometimes that the Gaussian can be folded multiple times in the finite frequency range. So, in principle it’s a Gaussian distribution with bounds and also folded. This fold may not be seen if the mean of the  Gaussian is precisely inside the bounds and the variance parameter is small enough that only the tail of the distribution is folded multiple times.

Is there a mathematical formula describing this type of generalised distribution? Or, am I asking the wrong question?

Comment: I almost posted an answer to the title of this post before realizing that you added something about folding in the body of the post... What is this folding operation?

Comment: For example if this Gaussian is a frequency spectrum, and we sample the time domain signal with a specific sampling rate, we can’t detect the frequencies that are out of the maximum frequency allowed by the sampling rate (Nyquist). Any frequency above that limit will be folded from the other side. It’s like an Ambiguous spectrum due to the sampling.

Comment: This is both intriguing and confusing. Sampling from a Gaussian in frequency space would entail possibilities such as negative frequencies and aliasing. Bounding the frequencies to $\left(0,\frac{f_s}{2}\right)$ where $\frac{f_s}{2}$ is the Nyquist frequency might make the problem nicer, but perhaps the less nice cases are your main concern?

Comment: Yes aliasing is the correct word. Yes I’m trying to estimate the parameters of this Gaussian frequency spectrum at the end. However, as the sampling makes it not nice (sometimes it’s nice), I want to make a general statement about the distribution. The first thing that comes to my mind is to limit it to $\left( 0, \frac{f_s}{2} \right)$ and consider the folding (aliasing). If I say my distribution is this (instead of a perfect Gaussian) and then if i estimate the parameters (in this case there can be more parameters I suppose) then my problem is simpler. Am I thinking right ?